# How to use new line character in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, linux-mint

I am trying to make a loop that will loop until the escape key is pressed but I have a struggle with printing the read message because if any key, except the enter key, it will continue to print in one line

Here is my code:

```
while : ; do
    read -n1 -r -p "Press esc key to continue...\n" key
    [[ $key != $'\e' ]] || break
done
```

It outputs `Press esc key to continue...\n`

Comment: Remove the '\n' from the `read` line. Add `echo -e "\n"` after the read line do a `echo -e "\n"`. You want to print the new line _not_ as part of the `read` logic. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/383197/bash-read-how-to-capture-n-newline-character?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: `echo "Press esc key to continue..."; read -n1 -r key`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$'...'` string like you're using for detecting escape character already:

```
while : ; do
    read -n1 -r -p $'Press esc key to continue...\n' key
    [[ $key != $'\e' ]] || break
done
```

As per `man bash`:

> Words of the form $'string' are treated specially.  The word expands to string, with backslash-escaped characters replaced as  specified  by  the  ANSI  C
>          standard.  Backslash escape sequences are `\n`, `\t`, `\e` etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'd restructure just a little bit!

1.) The input message ("Press esc key to continue...") shouldn't have an embedded newline. This newline, I'm assuming, should appear after the user presses escape.

1a.) We also don't want user input popping up on the screen, so read -s (silently) after echoing -n (no newline) your input prompt.

Original:

```
read -n1 -r -p "Press esc key to continue...\n" key
```

Modified:

```
echo -n "Press esc key to continue..."; read -s -n1 -r key
```

2.) Now, when the user presses ESC, I believe you'd like to initiate a newline & exit the loop, so just echo AND break on the ESC key press. Boom.

2a.) On the issue of everything BUT an escape re-printing the message...Well, let's do a carriage return if the user DOESN'T hit escape, that way the message is printed in the same spot instead of on a new line!

Original:

```
[[ $key != $'\e' ]] || break
```

Modified:

```
if [[ $key == $'\e' ]];then echo;break; else echo -ne "\033[0K\r"; fi
```

Finished version:

```
   while : ; do
     echo -n "Press esc key to continue..."; read -s -n1 -r key
     if [[ $key == $'\e' ]];then echo;break; else echo -ne "\033[0K\r"; fi
   done
```

Testing it (a bunch of random NON-ESCAPE keys):
[image]

Let me know if that works for you!